# AWK variable issue

Tags: bash, awk

The variable in awk does not return the result.

I am trying to get the next line of the matched value from file by using awk. It works fine without the variable. Thanks.

```
$ cat file
name=bobk
snm=sahh
emp=bklc
jdate=879
$
$ awk '/name/{getline; print}' file
snm=sahh   ---------> Got the result
$
$ export MYVAR=name
$
$ echo $MYVAR
name
$
$  awk -v AVAR=${MYVAR} '/AVAR/{getline; print}' file
$   ---------> No result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the regexp match operator `~` against the whole line `$0` as `/AVAR/` is match for the string `AVAR` not the variable `AVAR`:

```
$ awk -v AVAR=${MYVAR} '$0~AVAR{getline; print}' file
snm=sahh
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK variables to pass parameters is almost always cleaner as to intent; however, in this specific case, the resulting script is a bit more complex than it needs to be -- and breaking the rules a bit may actually be easier to understand and communicate to others.

With use of double-quotes to escape the script there is no need to use an additional AWK variable. That, and if we place the shell variable within /'s there is no need for the {}:

```
$ awk "/$MYVAR/ {getline; print}" file
snm=sahh
$
```